# Bootstrap navbar toggling items about center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Trying to create a Navbar in Bootstrap that toggles on smaller screen sizes. Unfortunately, when I press the toggle button, it pushes my logo up off the screen, as so. Seems to be an issue with the nested container inside the Navbar, as everything works once I remove it - but I'd like to keep the container classes' other behavior. Here is my code, and its behavior:

```
<nav class='navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white'>
  <div class='navbar-content container'>
    <a href='#top' class='navbar-brand my-auto mr-3' id='logo'>MG</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-links" aria-controls="navbar-links" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-links">
      <ul class='navbar-nav jump-to my-auto'>
        <li class='nav-item'><a href='#about' class='nav-link mx-1'>About</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a href='#skills'class='nav-link mx-1'>Skills</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a href='#projects' class='nav-link mx-1'>Projects</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a href='#places' class='nav-link mx-1'>Tastes + Travels</a></li>
        <li class='nav-item'><a href='#connect' class='nav-link mx-1'>Connect</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class='navbar-nav social-media mr-4 ml-auto pull-right'>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='https://www.facebook.com/milan.gupta.735' target='_blank' title='Facebook'><img src='images/social-media-icons/Facebook-icon.png' class='nav-link mx-1'></a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='https://twitter.com/MilanGuptaa' target='_blank' title='Twitter'><img src='images/social-media-icons/Twitter-icon.png' class='nav-link mx-1'></a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='https://www.instagram.com/mgupta99/' target='_blank' title='Instagram'><img src='images/social-media-icons/Instagram-icon.png' class='nav-link mx-1'></a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/milan-gupta/' target='_blank' title='LinkedIn'><img src='images/social-media-icons/LinkedIn-icon.png' class='nav-link mx-1'></a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id='nav-resume-link' class='nav-item nav-link px-4 py-2 pull-right' href='Resume.pdf' target='_blank' title='See My Resume'>RESUME</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Before toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyDpV.png)

[After toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOEgb.png)

Comment: It's hard to recreate your problem. Try putting it in a jsbin and post the link so we can see exactly what you see.

Comment: can you share your code of navbar to solve your problem ?

Comment: The above code is the code of the Navbar